# Не меняются значения value в php массиве

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Есть такой вид:

```
<?php if (!empty($products)):?>
             <?php foreach ($products as $product):?>
                <div class="col-xl-4">

                    <div class="dishes-item">
                        <img src="/img/products/no-foto.png" alt="3">
                        <h4><?= $product->name?></h4>
                        <p><?= $product->description?></p>
                        <div class="dishes-item-details">
                            <span class="weight"><span class="weight-size"><?= $product->weight?></span> гр</span> <span class="sum"><?= $product->price?> руб.</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dishes-item-counter">
                            Кол/во <input type="text" value="1" id="qty" data-id="<?= $product->id?>" class="dishes-item-counter-field" />
                            <a class="add_to_cart"  data-id="<?= $product->id?>"   href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['cart/add', 'id' => $product->id])?>"><button  class="btn btn-choose">Добавить</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php else:?>
                <h2>Здесь товаров пока нет</h2>
               <?php endif;?>
```

Скрипт к нему:

```
$('.add_to_cart').on('click',  function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id'), qty = $('#qty').val();
        console.log(qty)
          $.ajax({
           url: '/cart/add',
           data: {id: id, qty: qty},
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(res){
            if(!res) alert(ошибка);

              showCart(res);
           },
         error: function(){
               alert('Ошибка');
          }
       });
    });
```

Мне нужно методом get получить значение value в поле input. 
За массивом данное поле принимает все входящие значения, в массиве выдает значение 1, не смотря на введенные данные.

Comment: Как вы думаете,если создать несколько элементов с одинаковым id, то какой из них вам требуется через селектор "#qty"?

Comment: Я же указал id товара в data-id.

Comment: А я спрашиваю про #qty.

Comment: Я не понял вашего вопроса.

Comment: У вас есть 2,4,5 элементов с одинаковым id, какой из этих элементов должен вернуться вам через селектор (#qty)?